# Cannot get traffic when setting up transparent proxy mode for specific port

Tags: proxy, iptables, transparentproxy

I'd like to capture a HTTP service call from HostA -> HostB to test the client on HostA for replace the HTTP response. Both OS are Linux. I tried following but fail.
What's the recommended way to do this?

I would like to use transparent proxy mode because I cannot modify client and cannot redirect all traffic from HostA to hostB as other service also running on HostA. I'd like only redirect the connection of the client from host A to host B.
The client in Host A call a service on Host B on a certain port 10001 by HTTP.

I tried setup HostC with mitmproxy  (HostA and HostC are in the same subnet)
HostA (ip_A) -> HostC(ip_C) with mitmproxy-> HostB(ip_B) , I set the ip table to build transparent mode.

Following is what I setup for on HostA

```
sudo iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 10001 -j MARK --set-mark 1
sudo ip route add default via ip_C table 100
sudo ip rule add fwmark 0x1 table 100
```

On HostC

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 10001 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
mitmproxy -T --host
```

This doesn't work.  client on HostA connection timeout.
If I try traceroute on HostA

```
traceroute ip_B -p 10001 -T
```

It shows ip_B is unreachable on TCP from HostA

I also tried setup mitmproxy on HostA, but  when I try to redirect traffic of port 10001 
on HostA

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 10001 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
mitmproxy -T --host
```

The service call could be capture by mitmproxy on HostA but cannot get response.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Sorry for typo, it's 10001.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? You just want to see the traffic? Whats wrong with just using a switch with [port mirroring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_mirroring) turned on and wireshark or tcpdump?

Comment: Oh, I want to capture response and replace response for the request from HostA.

Comment: Perhaps a complete change of software might help see https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4239/what-software-to-modify-and-create-tcp-ip-packets

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps - once the packets gets to the MITM server its now going to port 8080 - but the HOST_A Web Server is still on 10001 - so won't you need to do another IPTABLES to put it back to 10001? 
I think your better than me at that but I'd guess

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to-port 10001
```

would do it